# Samsung Galaxy S9: TYPE_GEOMAGNETIC_ROTATION_VECTOR not present

Tags: android, android-sensors, samsung-galaxy

Samsung Galaxy S9 phone I have does not seem to have a sensor  [TYPE_GEOMAGNETIC_ROTATION_VECTOR](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_GEOMAGNETIC_ROTATION_VECTOR).

```
SensorMnagaer mSensorManager = (SensorManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GEOMAGNETIC_ROTATION_VECTOR)
```

The last line returns null.

```
mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL)
```

returns a list of 39 sensors but does not seem to have this specific sensor.

1. Is there a way to confirm that TYPE_GEOMAGNETIC_ROTATION_VECTOR is not present?
2. Is there anyway to replicate the behaviour of the sensor in software?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same using SENSOR_TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR:

```
getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);
```

The downside of that is that has more power consumption.